# Slick 2 generator: tables with same names on different schemas

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm using [Slick 2 code generator](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/code-generation.html) and so far so good, but there is one problem though. If I have 2 schemas on my Postgres database and each of those schemas have a table with the same name - code generator creates duplicate classes resulting in an obvious error. Is there a way to circumvent this? Is there a way to designate multiple schemas in one database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a know issue: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/593

You should be able to work around it by customizing the code generator. There is an attempt in there.